# Why does jQuery's $.each convert numbers to objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's each function executes the callback function in the context of the array's element:

```
$.each([3], function () {
    console.log(this === 3);
    console.log(this.valueOf() === 3);
});
```

I expected `true true`, but got `false true`. This indicates the array's elements get boxed by the each function.

My question has two parts:

- What is the motivation behind boxing the number?
- Can a new each function be written to work as I expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that when the `$.each()` callback is called using `.call()` and the `3` is passed as the first argument so that it will be the this pointer that javascript always boxes the `3` into an object since the `this` pointer is always supposed to be an object.

An interesting observation by Oleg is that in strict mode, you get `true` and `true` as the output.  See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hjpQG/

Again, thanks to Oleg, [here's a reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript) that describes that it's not boxed into an object in strict mode.

And, [an ECMAScript reference from apsillers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) that contains this step: `"Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg)"`.  This step happens internally in the JS engine in the process of calling a function in any way (when not in strict mode).

---

To work-around this in all browsers, you can either change the `===` to `==` or you can switch to using the 2nd argument passed to the callback which is the undisturbed value.

```
$.each([3], function (index, value) {
    // use value argument
    log(value === 3);
    log(this.valueOf() === 3);
});

$.each([3], function (index, value) {
    // double equals
    log(this == 3);
    log(this.valueOf() === 3);
});
```

Or, if you are only trying to support browsers that support strict mode, you can use strict mode with your original code.

Comment: I would like to add that under `'use strict';` it is returning the number itself.

Comment: @Oleg - interesting observation (I added to my answer with a demo).  Any idea why?

Comment: according to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) though (in the note) it says _"The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this value"_. So are the browsers just not doing this or am I missing some other process

Comment: Here it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript

Comment: @PatrickEvans - That section of the spec describes the two behaviors we're seeing.  One part of it says: "and ToObject is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the this value".

Comment: @PatrickEvans It happens in [10.4.3 Entering Function Code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3): "If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg. ...Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg)." `call`, `apply`, and `bind` just happen to be the only ways to get a non-object `this` at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually it says "This is a change from Edition 3 where (..) toObject is applied". This means that browsers haven't applied this change. I'm not sure about 10.4.3 though. It looks like these two paragraphs of EcmaScript contradict each other.

Comment: @freakish - see the reference from apsillers.

Comment: @jfriend00 OK, then 10.4.3 and 15.3.4.4 contradict each other.

Comment: @freakish No they don't -- 15.4.3.3 says that `call` passes its `thisArg` to the internal `[[Call]]` method withot modifying it. The [`[[Call]]` method then runs the steps in 10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1), which *do* modify `this`. The two sections run at different stages of function execution; they don't contradict each other.

Comment: @apsillers I see. That makes sense. I guess that the spec is just written in a very confusing way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

1) From [jQuery.each docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection,
>   whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the
>   callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each
>   time. **(The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but
>   Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is
>   a simple string or number value.)**

**this** is always an object in JavaScript.

2) You can rewrite your code something like this:

```
$.each([3], function (key, value) {
    console.log(value === 3);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uFhU/)

Comment: Thanks! This is the practical solution, but I'm wondering if there is any way to rewrite the each function without changing the definition of the callback function.

Comment: **this** is always object in JavaScript, so, I believe, you can't rewrite your function to work with condition **this === 3**.

Answer (score -6):

- What is the motivation behind boxing the number?

Because the first parameter needs to be an array:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Boxing a single number is javascript syntax for array with only one element.

Comment: Yes I do agree with this.